# Laragon - Possible troubles with composer when trying to launch /cloud.test

Tags: php, laravel, windows, installation, laragon

I've reinstalled phpstorm, laravel, laragon, composer... everything to work in my project from another machine (windows 10).

When I launch laragon (Full 6.0 220916) (php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64 [TS]) and click on web (after I moved to my project path on the terminal) it shows the localhost so I know it's working.

phpstorm on the other hand is also working and sync with github repo. Composer (2.4.1) (from term) also works and php artisan can be used.

The problem is that I can't open cloud.test to see changes before PR or merging to main branch. In my other machine it works perfectly but I installed everything with a lot of help (I'm relatively new in php!)... I'm not sure what could be the cause of the issue... Am I missing something obvious? Please let me know if you need me to provide more information!

---

**Edit**: solved! I had to follow these steps:

**Telling Laragon where's my project**

- Go to Laragon Preferences and change Document Root to my project's folder.
- Check \Windows32\drivers\etc\host file.

**Configuring the data Laragon will be using**

- Create the database inside Laragon.MySQL.
- Configure my `.env` file in my project

```
**APP_NAME= "My app name"**
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY= (generated from php artisan key:generate)
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=**myapp.url**, e.g., cloud.test

LOG_CHANNEL=daily
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=**Laragon.MySQL database name**
DB_USERNAME=**root** (check match in Laragon.MySQL > user data. 
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=localhost

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=
```

**Bringing data from project seeders**

- `Run php artisan key:generate`
- `Run php artisan migrate`